# binding jquery datatable gives error "Requested unknown parameter '0' from the data source for row 0"

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

i am creating json format for jquery datatable using jquery , 
but it gives error "DataTables warning (table id = 'tblDynamicModifierItems2'): Requested unknown parameter '0' from the data source for row 0"

my Html is

```
 <table id="tblDynamicModifierItems" class="tblDynamicModifierItems table table-hover table-nomargin dataTable table-bordered dataTable-scroller dataTable-tools">
                                <tbody></tbody>
                            </table>
```

my Jquery code is

```
var aaData = [];
     var ModifierItemCode = "1";
            var Description = "10 cane rum"
            aaData.push({
                "ModifierItemCode": ModifierItemCode,
                "ModifierItem": Description,
                "Delete": "Delete"
            });

     var oTable = $("#tblDynamicModifierItems").dataTable({
                    "aaData": aaData,
                    "aoColumns": [{ "bVisible": false }, { "sTitle": "Description" }, null],

                });
                oTable.fnSort([[1, 'asc']]);
```

can anyOne help me solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the markup right. jQuery dataTables is very sensitive to that. It is important to define the headers, `<th>`, so dataTables have a chance to know how many columns it should expect in each row of data.

```
<table id="tblDynamicModifierItems" class="tblDynamicModifierItems table table-hover table-nomargin dataTable table-bordered dataTable-scroller dataTable-tools">
    <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>ModifierItemCode</th>
           <th>ModifierItem</th>
           <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>    
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Also, you must tell dataTables which part of each `aaData` item that should correspond to which column :

```
var oTable = $("#tblDynamicModifierItems").dataTable({
     "aaData": aaData,
     "aoColumns": [
         { mDataProp : "ModifierItemCode" },
         { mDataProp : "ModifierItem" },         
         { mDataProp : "Delete" }
     ]     
});
```

your code in a demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/s9Lag6mc/**

Regarding your `"aoColumns": [{ "bVisible": false }, { "sTitle": "Description" }, null],` I am not completely sure what you are trying to do, but if you want to hide the first column, just add `bVisible: false` to the first `aoColumns` item, and so on.

---

As for your `fnCreatedRow` problem : Think about it, you are inserting an object. So instead of `alert(aData[0])` (or whatever) simply

```
alert(aData.ModifierItemCode);
```

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/0aLys2d3/**

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply, your code is working fine, Thnak you so much agin.

Comment: I have one more question, i wnat do set attribute Id when row is created, so i m doing like this, 
var oTable = $("#tblDynamicModifierItems").dataTable({
     "aaData": aaData, 
"fncreatedrow": function (nrow, adata, idataindex) {
                    alert("Abhijit")
                    $(nrow).attr('id', 'tr' + adata[0]);
                },
     "aoColumns": [
         { mDataProp : "ModifierItemCode" },
         { mDataProp : "ModifierItem" },         
         { mDataProp : "Delete" }
     ]     
}); but
 here i m not getting my ALERT. Any Reason

Comment: @AbhijitPandya You are welcome :) Have you tried with `fnCreatedRow`? C and R in uppercase. JS variables is case sensitive, datatables triggers a `fnCreatedRow` not a `fncreatedrow`.

Comment: i have not tried this, now its working, i m getting alert now, thank you very much again.

Comment: in same above while  fnCreatedRow, i can not get aData[0], i am getting here "undefined"..

Comment: hello, i need your little help, in above code in fnCreatedRow function i have passed aData, but i can not get data, 
 "fnCreatedRow": function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
                    alert(aData[0]);
                    alert(aData[1]);
                    alert(aData[2]);
                    $(nRow).attr('id', 'tr' + aData[0]);
                    $(nRow).css('cursor', 'pointer');
                },
i cant get any ALERT here, is there any problem here?

Comment: hey @AbhijitPandya, have updated the answer regarding dealing with `fnCreatedRow` or `aData[0]` etc. Post a new question if you have other problems.